# Storing parameterized values in cloud formation and referencing it

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

Is there a way to store variables in Cloudformation?
I've created a resource with a name which is a stage specific name in the following form:

```
DeliveryStreamName: {'Fn::Sub': ['firehose-events-${Stage}', 'Stage': {'Ref' : 'Stage' }]}
```

Now if I've to create a cloudwatch alarm on that resource I'm again following the same pattern:

```
Dimensions:
   - Value: {'Fn::Sub': ['firehose-events-${Stage}', 'Stage': {'Ref' : 'Stage' }]}
```

Instead if I could store the whole value in one variable, it would be much easier for me to refer it.

I thought initially storing it in parameters, like this:

```
Parameters:
   FirehoseEvent: {Type:String, Default: 'firehose-events-${Stage}'}
```

But the stage value doesn't seem to get passed in here. And there is no non default value either for this resource name.
The other option I considered was using mapping, but that defeats the purpose of using `${Stage}`.

Is there some other way which I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly you haven't missed anything. **Parameters can't reference other parameters** in their definition.

The only way I can think of doing what you which would be through a custom [macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63642976/storing-parameterized-values-in-cloud-formation-and-referencing-it). In its simplest form the macro would just perform traditional `find-and-replace` type of template processing.

However, the time required to develop such macro could be not worth its benefits, at least in this simple example you've provided in the question.